# Not able to display the version number in document while editing in word

Tags: 2013, versioning, document-template

I have a document library in which the users create new document from the template. I want to display the version number of document in the header.

I performed the steps which are described in [this](http://www.codebycody.com/2011/07/add-sharepoint-version-number-to-word.html) article.

It shows the version correctly until it is major version.

When the document is published and gets major version then it displays minor version only.

For ex: I performed the following steps.

1. Created new document and edited from document library at that time version displayed 0.1 which is correct.
2. Then workflow started and there was only one approver1. Meanwhile the worklfow was not completed, I opened the document in word and it displayed 0.2 version which is also correct.
3. Approved the document and published the document as major version then it displays 0.3 instead of 1.0

Below is the image of document library view which displays the correct version.

[image: Image of document library view where the document template is uploaded]

Below is the image of document which displays the incorrect version.

[image: Image of document in opened in word application.]

Answer (score 0):

because you can publish when a document is opend, (usually cannot edit properties when the file is open) 
in the list a version dispay 1.0 and in document it's until display 0.3.
for refresh properties in the file reopen it